# VSJitDebugger fails

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I tried the 'Image File Execution Options' trick to automatically attach to a sub process of my debuggee. However, vsjitdebugger fails to start any .NET process (neither through 'Image File Execution Options' nor directly via command line), it pops up an error message:

[image: Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger - An error occured while launching Path\To\Exe: The application cannot be started. The application depends on the Microsoft .NET Framework and the version of the Framework installed is corrupt or incompatible. Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.]

Of course, the documentation mentions several errors, but not the one which happens to me.

I'm working using Visual Studio 2005 on Windows 7, and the destination process is compiled for .NET 2.0.

Thanks a lot!

Addition: All available service packs and security updates (including the Windows Vista Fix) are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a newer release of Visual Studio for other reasons (both VS 2008 and VS 2010 in this case) apparently also solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking for / installing the .Net framework 2.0?

Don't assume that its going to be installed just because its a Windows 7 machine - [Windows is not a .NET Framework delivery channel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx)

Comment: When I try to install the .NET Framework 2.0 dotnetfx.exe, it fails with the error message that this framework is already installed as part of my operating system. This is what I expected, as Windows 7 contains the framework 3.5 which is a superset of 2.0.